# assigning values to a variable in if condition in php

Tags: php, if-statement, variable-assignment

Can anybody explain how assigning values to variables work in php. I have the following code which does not work as expected (by me).

```
if ( $account = $this->getClientAccount($request) )
{
     echo $account;
}
```

If I use this code account is 1, just ONE. How come??? getClientAccount returns string (username) or false if not user found. When user is found that 1 is returned. 
If I move the assignment above if statement, it works fine. I have similar problem when assining array returned by function to variable in if statement.

**EDIT**

Alright, guys I think I discovered something, at least something for all of us here.
Look at this code: http://codepad.org/QWjwl3vQ
I think you will understand what is happening. Just try test1() and test2()

Comment: Why semi colon in if statement condition ?

Comment: edited. removed that semicolon. It was not in my code actually

Comment: If possible show your func. `getClientAccount`, so that one can have a better idea.

Comment: Pay attention to my words: If I move the assignment above if statement, it works fine, as expected

Comment: Please have a look on edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After edit & checking your code it seems that boolean value is getting over write on the actual value. To get rid of this thing you need round braces on each condition for proper assignment called [Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Check your [code](http://codepad.org/nT7yIjq6) that I have edited to make work as you expected.

Comment: You made it. Thanks a lot. But I didn`t get why it was not working without extra braces

Comment: Your welcome !! Check the operator precedence reference I added in my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

The first block of code is *syntactically* wrong.

```
if
    (
        $account = $this->getClientAccount($request); // <--- This semicolon here must be removed
    )
{
     echo $account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not a real question and there is no point in trying to answer it directly, especially *if* you aren't familiar with PHP syntax.

It's the OP's *premises* have to be questioned, not the code he's posted.

*This* code will plainly output the result of getClientAccount method (unless it's 0 or empty array).

So, the OP have to check what "was in the code actually" *once more* or verify the actual result of getClientAccount function.

Comment: This your new question is totally different from one you asked. You have to make your mind *before* asking a question.

Comment: It is exactly same thing. Read it carefully!

Comment: if you still think there is no difference, then you didn't get the answer you accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
$staff_id_id = 0;
$salary = new salary();

$result = $salary -> getSalary($id);

// print_r($result);
$inv = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$staff_id = isset($inv['staff_id']) ? $inv['staff_id'] : '';
$present_days = isset($inv['present_days']) ? $inv['present_days'] : '30';
$total_days = isset($inv['total_days']) ? $inv['total_days'] : '30';
$advance_deducted = isset($inv['advance_deducted']) ? $inv['advance_deducted'] : '1';
$installment_deducted = isset($inv['installment_deducted']) ? $inv['installment_deducted'] : '0';

// print_r($inv);


$staff_name1 = isset($inv['staff_id']) ? $inv['staff_id'] : '';

if ($staff_name1 == $staff_id) {
  echo $staff_id++;
  //print_r($staff_id);
  //die();
  // echo $staff_name1;
}


if ($staff_id > 0) {
  echo "this user had already assign Vouchers";
}

else {



  $salary = new salary();

  $result = $salary -> getSalary($id);

  // print_r($result);
  $inv = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);



  $staff_id = isset($inv['staff_id']) ? $inv['staff_id'] : '';
  //print_r($staff_id);

  $date = isset($inv['date']) ? $inv['date'] : '';

  $advance_deducted = isset($inv['advance_deducted']) ? $inv['advance_deducted'] : '1';

  $installment_deducted = isset($inv['installment_deducted']) ? $inv['installment_deducted'] : '0';

  $installment_amount = isset($inv['installment_amount']) ? $inv['installment_amount'] : '';

  $paid_amount = isset($inv['paid_amount']) ? $inv['paid_amount'] : '';

  $total_days = isset($inv['total_days']) ? $inv['total_days'] : '30';

  $present_days = isset($inv['present_days']) ? $inv['present_days'] : '30';

  $amount_left = (isset($inv['amount_left']) && $inv['amount_left'] != NULL) ? $inv['amount_left'] : '0';

  $salary_id = isset($inv['id']) ? $inv['id'] : '';
```

Answer (score -1):

remove semicolon from if condition like following

```
if
(
    $account = $this->getClientAccount($request)
)
{
    echo $account;
}
```

and in your case php will check the value of $account variable after getting the returned value from the getClientAccount() function. if $account value ultimately mean true then it will execute your echo statement.

if you have any confusion about php boolean values then you can try it another way:

```
$account = $this->getClientAccount($request);
if(strlen($account)>0){
    echo $account;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are few syntax error. You need to remove the semi colon as mentioned already and you need to change to:

```
$account == $this->getClientAccount($request)
```

To check for a condition, at the moment you are trying to assign $account to $this->getClientAccount($request) result in a if statement. If statements are used to check conditions not to assign values.

Also $account already has to have a value otherwise your condition will always remain false, if the function returns a value.